# Pass Query string to mvc view action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor, query-string

I want to return to same page with error message along with `query string` when the model is invalid in post operation

My code is here

```
public ActionResult Action1(string Key)
{

    // do something
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action1(Model user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
    // do some stuff here
    }
    else
     // redirect to same page with query string key and also error message
}
```

Please suggest the line I need to add when the model is invalid to stay in the same page by showing the error message.

Comment: [This might help you](http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-mvc-custom-error-pages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action1(Model user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
    // do some stuff here
    }
    else
    {
        return this.RedirectToAction ("Action1", new { value1 = "QueryStringValue" });
    }
}
```

That would return this :

```
/controller/Action1?value1=QueryStringValue
```

**Also as per your comment.** 
You can use below approach for model instead of sending errors from controller to view for model failing.

```
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [StringLength(40)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [StringLength(1000, MinimumLength = 8)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [System.Web.Mvc.Compare("Password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string PasswordConfirmation { get; set; }
```

Comment: But here the error messages are not showing, this is equal to RedirectToAction(), I need view()

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. What do you mean by not getting error messages?

Comment: If the model is invalid, I can show some error message like length should be more than 6 or the password and confirm password do not match, it is not showing

Answer (score 3):

```
public ActionResult Action1(Model user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       // all is okay
    }
    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
    return View(model);
}
```